# Set Value to Variable in MySQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, null, declaration

I Create a MySql trigger and declare a variable. then i have some if condition. inside if cannot be set values to that declared variable out side of if. it's Possible? because i need that variable data to another functions. i'm always getting null.

This is my sample code
Setting Query get value when it Execute

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER Table1INSERTCustomer
    AFTER INSERT ON Table1
    FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE CustomerId integer;

IF (SELECT CustomerID FROM Seller WHERE Id = NEW.ResellerID AND CustomerID IS NOT NULL) 
THEN 
BEGIN

SET @CustomerId := (SELECT CustomerID FROM Seller WHERE Id = NEW.ResellerID LIMIT 1); <-- This is Problem

END; 
END IF;

END; 
$$
```

Thank You Very Much

Comment: `DECLARE CustomerId integer;` and `SET @CustomerId :=` are two different variables. First is declared variable local to compound statement, second in user-defined variable local to connection. *i need that variable data to another functions* Store this value in some service table.

Comment: Hi Akina Thanks for the replying. So how do i assign Value to main declared variable ?

Comment: Simply `SELECT CustomerID INTO CustomerId FROM Seller WHERE Id = NEW.ResellerID LIMIT 1`. But after trigger finished this variable will be destroyed, and its value will be lost.

Comment: I did but Same issue happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modelling example.

> ```
> create table test1 (id int, val int);
> ```

> ```
> insert into test1 values (1,11), (2,22);
> ```

> ```
> select * from test1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |  11
>  2 |  22
> ```

> ```
> create table test2 (id int, val int);
> ```

> ```
> create trigger tr 
> after insert on test2
> for each row
> select test1.val into @var 
> from test1 
> where test1.id = NEW.id;
> ```

> ```
> insert into test2 values (1,111);
> ```

> ```
> select * from test1;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 |  11
>  2 |  22
> ```

> ```
> select * from test2;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | val
> -: | --:
>  1 | 111
> ```

> ```
> select @var;
> ```
>
> ```
> | @var |
> | ---: |
> |   11 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1fd24971b1ec2b891fe03deadd84291f)*

Study. Apply.